# How to get the remaining time until next cycle shift?

Tags: rpc, api, programming

In TzStats block explorer, there is a gauge that shows how much time is left until next Tezos cycle shift.

Is there an RPC endpoint that retrieves this information?
Or is this info available in any of the known APIs like Baking Bad, TzKt or others?

How to get the remaining time until next cycle shift?

Comment: when answering your own question, don't forget to "accept" your answer so it marks the question as closed/answered

Comment: Ok. Sorry for not doing it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found it:

TzKt API v1:

[https://api.tzkt.io/v1/cycles/[cycle_number]](https://api.tzkt.io/v1/cycles/%5Bcycle_number%5D)

```
index   599
firstLevel  3366913
startTime   "2023-04-16T00:30:59Z"
lastLevel   3383296
endTime "2023-04-18T21:29:50Z"
snapshotIndex   3
snapshotLevel   3272704
randomSeed  "b7395eff6371e7a1b2d686681bae57c9b01b16f7476f422cb25703370e2b1de9"
totalBakers 421
totalStaking    693572874904292
totalDelegators 189355
totalDelegated  573876710461203
selectedBakers  410
selectedStake   692113811106063
totalRolls  0
```